# Ntrig configuration

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

I would like to view/change some configurations for my DuoSense touchscreen (Ntrig), but I fail to find anything useful on Google.

So far what I've found were the following:

- [Ubuntu Wiki on Ntrig-calibration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Calibration/Ntrig) -> abandoned and can't install anymore
- [Launchpad Ntrig-utils](https://launchpad.net/ntrig-utils) -> same
- A forum discussion on Launchpad (oif/+question/181329) -> couldn't find anything useful (due to not enough rep points, I can't post the link)

Any idea where I can get some infos or (even better) documentations on this topic?

Comment: Related: https://web.archive.org/web/20150318140957/http://www.n-trig.com/wintab-2/

Comment: It looks like this startup got swallowed by MIcrosoft.. http://www.wsj.com/articles/microsoft-to-pay-around-30-million-for-n-trig-sources-1430415194